# Combining R plots with other R output

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to do something that seems like this. It should be simple but I've been beating my head against a wall all week.  I have a data frame with 256 columns from which I'm generating all unique combinations of 2x2 tables using `table()`, run statistics on the tables, like `chisq.test()` and `oddsratios()` while using `sink()` to pipe the output to a file.  The problem comes when I want to embed plots with the text.  I'd like to have the first section of each table contain histograms of the two variables but plots and text do not seem to mix.  I've not been able to find anything about how to redirect the plot device.  As an aside, I gotten to where if I use `X11()` and `par()` I can get a multi-plot figure to a plot output file.  So I can do the two things I want, but not at the same time.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please show us the sample code and output

Comment: I would suggest using knitr with LaTeX to create a file with tables, plots, and text. Otherwise, write them with figures to images with png(...) and include them in text files alone.

Answer (score 0):

The R package knitr (http://yihui.name/knitr/) is designed to do exactly what you want to do. It allows you to produce annotated reports of your data in html format with text and plots interspersed in the same file. It is particularly effective when used within the (free) R IDE R Studio (http://www.rstudio.com/).

If you're really set on putting your text results into the same files as your plots, you'd do better to annotate the plots with text than the other way around. You can, for instance, make a plot, and add your chisq.test p-value and chi squared value to the plot with the mtext() or text() function. Here's an example using cor.test instead of chisq.test:

```
xx <- rnorm(30, mean=5, sd=4) # some random numbers
yy <- xx + rnorm(30, mean=2, sd=3.5) # add noise to those random numbers
png("plot.png") # open a png device
plot(xx, yy) 
xy.cor <- cor.test(xx, yy) # run the correlation test
# print the test results to the plot margins
mtext(paste("R squared =", round(cor.test(xx, yy)$estimate, 2), 
"p value =", xy.cor$p.value), side=3)
dev.off() # close the png device
```